# FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 43118

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I need to show the google map and pinpoint some locations using a custom marker. My Application randomly crashes on the Android 11 devices and I got this error.

````
/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 43118
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16 (150400-0):11)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.aj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16 (150400-0):3)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.gl.g.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16 (150400-0):18)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bs.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16 (150400-0):14)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.av.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214516081@21.45.16 (150400-0):44)```
````